# Angular 2 call a function based on class applied on a div

Tags: javascript, css, angular, ng-class

I have a div with *ngFor to loop though an array of messages.

```
<div *ngFor="let message of messages;  let i=index" 
 [focused]="i === activeIndex;" [ngClass]="{'message-list-active': activeIndex === i  }" 
(click)="onAddtoMessage(message.id); activeIndex = i"></div>
```

I am applying `class "message-list-active"` on focused item, and this message changes color to blue.

I have a click event when I click I am able to pass the message id.

The question is how can I pass the ids by not clicking, but pass ids of the messages that have 'message-list-active' applied. As in future random messages can be selected by default, and I need their ids.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a function in `[ngClass]`

```
<div *ngFor="let message of messages;  let i=index" 
 [focused]="i === activeIndex;" [ngClass]="{
        'message-list-active': activeClass(i, message)
 }" 
(click)="onAddtoMessage(message.id); activeIndex = i"></div>


activeClass(index, message){
   if(index === this.activeIndex){console.log(message.id)}
   return index === this.activeIndex;
}
```

Comment: I am logging ids and it just prints ids of every message, but I need id only the ones that have class "message-list-active" applied

Comment: can't you filter out that in the function, just put up condition

Comment: dude i don;t know what is your messges array has, you didn't add that here, what you wanted was on this condition `index === this.activeIndex`  you want to add the class and you want to see the id of that object, so you're getting it, now check you messages array you might have problem there, you might have all id's as 1 or whatever, stackoverflow gives idea not the exact solution

Comment: thanks for the answer, it helped a lot, will post the problem I had when I find